# Call History Location

Tags: iphone, ios, history, phone.app

When I go to 'Recents' in iPhone, I can see the location of my callers. I'm wondering how this location is determined.

Is it the exact location of the caller at the time of the call, or just where the area code is registered?

Answer (score 1):

It's just a basic area code lookup. It may not be the actual location of the caller.

Comment: I don't know the exact mechanism, but agree it appears to be based on calling number, but not area code. In Australia area code is 2 digits, which would only give 7 locations plus mobile. Locations are given to finer granularity.